# Can we use two ad networks app-ads.txt combined in the root of our domain

Tags: admob, startapp, app-ads.txt

I am new to the ad networks i have used admob app-ads.txt file in the root of our site but now i want to add another ad network(startapp) to my app which also have app-ads.txt file so my question is can we use these both app-ads.txt files in one txt file. I am new so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is yes, look for example the app-ads.txt of a platform like onefootball or fantamaster:

https://onefootball.com/app-ads.txt

https://www.fantamaster.it/app-ads.txt

Answer (score 2):

No Admob access App-ads.txt from root domain you can use free hosting tool for it or Add pubid in same app-ads.txt

Like this

```
google.com, pub-0000000000000000, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
google.com, pub-0000000000000000, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```